# Are there any ELU-specific hats?

Tags: discussion, winterbash

Is it true that some sites have site-specific hats? If so, I believe these may all be secret ones.  For example, there is a  rumor of **tinfoil hats** available over at Area 51, but this is not confirmed yet.

Here are a few secret hats (circled) that turned up at MSO:

[image: hat pic]

But I have no idea of the circled ones are general or site-specific.

Do we have any secret hats of our own at ELU?

Answer (score 5):

Ok, it looks like there may not be per-site hats after all.  From [this MSO post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/159325/153355):

> When we were going to do custom hats for each site, we talked about tinfoil hats for MSO and Skeptics (as a joke!) but then realized: there just wasn't time. We'll consider them for next year, as hopefully we'll have time for per-site hats in the future.

It might even be true. Time will tell.