# Are we getting hats this year?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, winterbash-2013

A [question on Meta.GD.SE](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/708/hats-or-no-hats) asks whether they want to participate in a Hat-Fest like [ELU did last year](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3460/are-there-any-elu-specific-hats).

I **guess** that because there isn't a similar question here, it might actually be a foregone conclusion that ELU will get them again.

Or it might not be and it could be that we've been forgotten; or it's every other year; or I haven't noticed that People Said No.

Are we getting Hats for Christmas 2013? I want them. I rather enjoyed it.

[Not sure if this should be a feature-request or not. Probably not.]

Comment: Bah humbug.....

Comment: It's more that I was too lazy to write up a meta post and just wanted to poll the other mods internally first... but hey, now we have a post!

Comment: @badass there'll be a special button just for you that pretty much says just that! I think you'll even be allowed to click it. I think.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Really? Gee thanks, I'll be looking forward to it :D

Comment: For those of us who weren’t here a year ago … huh?!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet http://stackexchange.com/promos/12/winter-bash

Comment: Shouldn't the hats have arrived by now?

Comment: I think the hats are detained in the harbor of some port awaiting the end of a shipping industry strike.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, we are getting hats this year! Stay tuned for more information.

Comment: Yay! Yay! I enjoyed hats very much! Thank you!

Comment: Please make sure the hats are warm.

Thanks.

Comment: Hats for Xmas? Or when?

Comment: @Pitarou [One of the hats](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/lchaim) is very warm.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Hats now!

Comment: A bit late joining in, but thank you!

Answer (score 3):

**[We now have hats!](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/)**

Comment: Yes, but I don't have a unicorn hat - hence meta comments.

Answer (score 1):

Can I have the marauder hat please?

Comment: You've seen the marauder question right?